# How to plot an animated graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, ffmpeg

Following along [How to Create Animated Graphs in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-animated-graphs-in-python-bb619cc2dec1) when constructing an animated plot then on writing the ffmpeg I get the following error:

```
'Requested MovieWriter ({}) not available'.format(name))
RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available
```

After getting this error, I initially tried to install ffmpeg using `pip` by the following method:

```
python -m install ffmpeg
```

and it seems to have successfully installed ffmpeg, but going back to my code I still get the same error

Find below my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

overdoses = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\overdose_data_1999-2015.xls',sheet_name='Online',skiprows =6)

def get_data(table,rownum,title):
    data = pd.DataFrame(table.loc[rownum][2:]).astype(float)
    data.columns = {title}
    return data

title = 'Heroin Overdoses'
d = get_data(overdoses,18,title)
x = np.array(d.index)
y = np.array(d['Heroin Overdoses'])
overdose = pd.DataFrame(y,x)
overdose.columns = {title}
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 161, in __getitem__
    return self.avail[name]
KeyError: 'ffmpeg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 164, in __getitem__
    'Requested MovieWriter ({}) not available'.format(name))
RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you have not installed `ffmpeg` (properly). It almost looks a permission problem during installation? Try to uninstall/clean out `ffmpeg` and do a proper reinstall.

I see that you are trying to follow [“How to Create Animated Graphs in Python.”](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-animated-graphs-in-python-bb619cc2dec1) Why not just skipping the `ffmpeg` part altogether and just do a `plt.show()` at the end to see the animation.